# dijkstra's algorithm in time $O(k|V|+|E|)$

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

Can somebody can help me with this problem:

I have to calculate the minimum distance from a source node $s$ for undirected and connected graphs $G = ( V, E)$ with weights on the arcs belonging to the set $\{ 1, 2, . . . , k \}$, where $k$ is a fixed integer.

> Implement Dijkstra's algorithm taking advantage of the peculiarity of
>   these graphs so that the minimum distances to be calculated in $O ( k |  V | + | E |)$.

I've no idea how to solve this problem. I don't need the specific code , but I need an algorithmic idea . Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Use an array / list that you can do random access on as the priority queue instead of using a binary tree.

**More hint**: Suppose you have a super large array $q$. Now, whenever you "push" a value $i$ into the queue, place it into $q[i]$. Instead of popping the queue, you loop the queue from the smallest to largest index.

Comment: Dijkstra is usually $O(V \log E + E)$ right? What is the part that causes the $\log E$?

Comment: log E is caused by the update of the heap

Comment: @GabrieleSaturni Correct. Now, instead of using a heap, use an array. Update becomes $O(1)$. Read my "more hint".

Comment: ahhh okok now i understand , in this case i don't need the heap beacause the weights on the arcs is limited ...so it's sufficient do a loop from 1 to k and adding the nodes that have weight 1 to nodes that have weight k , of course , using the idea of dijkastra. Right??

Comment: @GabrieleSaturni Nope, the loop must goes from $1$ through $kV$, since the longest possible path is of length $kV$. The insert is $O(1)$, but the loop is **amortized** $O(kV)$.

Comment: yes , i understand that but my english isnt'good XD . I wanted to say that . XD